# Contest problem on the divisibility of an integer by $n!$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

This question is the $4$th question in part A of the Simon Marais Math Competition, $2022$ (held about $2$ weeks back).

> Let $n$ be a positive integer, and $q \geq 3$ an odd integer such that every prime factor of $q$ is larger than $n$. Then $$
> \frac{1}{n!} \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{q^i-1}{q-1}
> $$
> is an integer that has no prime factor in common with $\frac{q-1}{2}$.

This is a competition for undergraduate students, therefore I expected a typical olympiad technique to be used here. That $q-1$ divides $q^i-1$ is obvious. We want to show that $n!$ divides this quotient.

Let $p \leq n$ be odd, and $p | q-1$. By Lifting the Exponent, $\nu_p(\frac{q^i-1}{q-1}) = \nu_p(q^i-1)-\nu_p(q-1) = \nu_p(i)$. Thus, $\nu_p(\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{q^i-1}{q-1}) = \sum_{i=1}^n \nu_p(i) = \nu_p(n!)$. If $p=2$ then $p$ divides $q-1$, and LTE for $p=2$ does the trick again.

However, if $p \nmid q-1$ then as $p \nmid q$, $q^{k(p-1)} \equiv 1 \mod p$ for all $k$... and I'm not sure what to do. It is not clear to me that $\nu_p(\prod_{i=1}^n(q^i-1)) \geq \nu_p(n!)$. Certainly it is true that the number of $i$ such that $q^i-1$ is a multiple of $p$ is bigger than the number of multiples of $p$ less than $n$. However, accounting for $p^2,p^3$ etc. is the problem. I'd want to know if someone can continue and finish this approach.

I assume that it's enough to show that it is an integer. Once that occurs, it should not be difficult to show that $\nu_{p}((q-1)/2)>0$ implies that $p$ doesn't divide that fraction, using LTE and breaking into cases $p=2,p \neq 2$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Right, I didn't see that you're extended it for all $p$. I'll remove the edit. The key idea is nice : even if $p$ doesn't divide $q-1$, it still does divide $q^d-1$ for some $d$, and one can apply LTE with that $d$. You're right about the flag variety as well : $q$ needs to be a prime power of $p$. I just wonder if all this counting can be done with a weaker notion of a field (only groups might suffice). Of course there will be more technicalities, but can that approach be pulled through? I'll take a look.

Comment: The second part of the problem is IMO trivial, I wouldn't need a solution for it.

Comment: (for the lazy: https://www.simonmarais.org/2022.html)

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thank you very much. I am attempting another question from that paper, and will ask it here if it turns out to be out of my reach.

Answer (score 5):

Let $d = \text{ord}_p(q)$ be the smallest positive integer $d$ such that $q^d \equiv 1 \bmod p$, so that $q^i \equiv 1 \bmod p$ iff $d \mid i$. By Fermat's little theorem, $d \mid p-1$, so in particular $d \le p-1$. This gives, without even using LTE, that

$$\nu_p \left( \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{q^i - 1}{q - 1} \right) \ge \left\lfloor \frac{n}{d} \right\rfloor \ge \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p-1} \right\rfloor \ge \nu_p(n!).$$

I haven't thought about the second part of the problem. I can't resist mentioning that if $q$ is a prime power there is a much more direct proof of this divisibility: in this case it follows by [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)) applied to the fact that the [general linear group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_group) $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$, which has order $q^{{n \choose 2}} \prod_{i=1}^n (q^i - 1)$, has a subgroup of order $(q - 1)^n n!$, namely the [generalized permutation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_permutation_matrix) or monomial matrices, which abstractly are the wreath product $\mathbb{F}_q^{\times} \wr S_n$. If every prime factor of $q$ is larger than $n$ then $(q - 1)^n n!$ is relatively prime to $q^{ {n \choose 2} }$ so that factor can be ignored.

I also can't resist mentioning some more interesting facts. The polynomial $[n]_q! = \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{q^i - 1}{q - 1}$ is known as the [$q$-factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-analog#%22Classical%22_q-theory) and many fun things are known about it. Its coefficients have a combinatorial interpretation in terms of permutations, and also as the [Betti numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betti_number) of a manifold called a [flag variety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_flag_variety). If $q$ is a prime power it counts the number of [complete flags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_(linear_algebra)) in the vector space $\mathbb{F}_q^n$, and the relationship between this count and the fact about Betti numbers comes from the [Weil conjectures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weil_conjectures).

Comment: Yes, yes! Now then, I am aware of the fact that $GL_n(\mathbb F_q)$ has that particular order. I knew that finding a subgroup of some order involving $n!$ would be enough. Unfortunately, I went down the wrong road : at this point, I left the $GL_n$ interpretation alone and instead went to the simpler $\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{q^i-1}{q-1} = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} q^{inv(\sigma)}$, and tried figuring out if this was clearly divisible by $n!$. Turns out that it's also quite non-trivial, but thanks for your contributions.